# optimizing a query with that's adding stuff to the current time in the WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that's doing, among other things, this:

```
AND TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL li.tzOffset HOUR - INTERVAL li.dst HOUR) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
```

The problem is that it's not very performant but it is unclear to me if there's a way to make it more performant. Neither tzOffset or dst are indexed. Would indexing them help?

I'm currently running MySQL 5.6 but expect I'll be upgrading to 5.7 within a week or two, probably. If MySQL 8.0 has features that'd speed queries like this up then that would be good to know, too, so that I can make the case for us spending the time to work on that

Comment: I'm no expert with mysql processing speed function-by-function, but I'm wondering if you see any improvements with `TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL (li.tzOffset - li.dst) HOUR) BETWEEN... ` assuming it's allowed.

Comment: If you can rephrase the search predicate to isolate the columns on the left side of the comparison, then there will be a much better chance of improving the performance of the query. For example, if you can transform `now() + offset - dst between 8 and 20` to `offset - dst between 8 - now() and 20 - now()` then a indexed, stored virtual column can be indexed to allow index searched on it.

Answer (score 1):

See [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Worse than that, you have essentially

```
WHERE function(variable1, variable2) BETWEEN ...
```

If there were some way to combine `li.tzOffset - li.dst` into a single column, then you could do

```
WHERE new_column BETWEEN ...
```

which *might* be able to use an `INDEX` involving `new_column`

I think that indexed generated columns was added in 5.7.  Without "generated columns", you would need to add a new column and compute that difference into it.